# Como consumir servicio soap desde vue js

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, xmlhttprequest

Hola como puedo consumir un servicio soap desplegado en azure desde vuejs estaba intentando hacerlo con XMLHttpRequest pero no funciona ya que sale esto:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://service.service' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

psdta: el servicio no lo realice yo, solo debo consumirlo

Comment: Por favor retroalimenta tu pregunta con más información, ejemplos, códigos de prueba, resultados obtenidos, etcétera. Todo para que tengas más oportunidades de que alguien colabore a ayudarte y a resolver tu problema. Te invito a que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)